# How to parse object to array one by one using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below json data,

```
{
    "componants": [{
        "category": "screensets",
        "position": "top",
        "rotate": "180",
        "3d_file": "3d_deg_180.obj",
        "height": "10",
        "width": "10",
        "x": "239",
        "y": "186",
        "current_roate": "0",
        "comp_color": ""
    }, {
        "category": "screensets",
        "position": "top",
        "rotate": "180",
        "3d_file": "3d_deg_180.obj",
        "height": "10",
        "width": "10",
        "x": "619",
        "y": "186",
        "current_roate": "0",
        "comp_color": ""
    }, {
        "category": "screensets",
        "position": "top",
        "rotate": "180",
        "3d_file": "3d_deg_180.obj",
        "height": "10",
        "width": "10",
        "x": "379",
        "y": "86",
        "current_roate": "0",
        "comp_color": ""
    }],
    "width": "640",
    "height": "640",
    "name": "Test Drawing",
    "size": "40",
    "screen": "Conference set"
}
```

How to parse this value using jquery?

Comment: what you want to parse? do you want to to convert into string 
? can you explain in detail

Comment: `obj['componants' ]` is an array

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what the desired output format is. What do you mean "one by one"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you try to manipulate your object to array like this below ?

```
[
  {
    "width"    : "640",
    "height"   : "640",
    "name"     : "Test Drawing",
    "size"     : "40",
    "screen"   : "Conference set",
    "category" : "screensets",
    "position" : "top",
    "rotate"   : "180",
    "3d_file"  : "3d_deg_180.obj",
    "height"   : "10",
    "width"    : "10",
    "x" : "379",
    "y" : "86",
    "current_roate" : "0",
    "comp_color"    : ""
  }

  ...
]
```

You can try this one :)

```
var obj = { ... }; // your object
obj = $.map(obj.componants,
  function(val, idx) {
    return $.extend(
      {  width : obj.width,
         height: obj.height,
         name  : obj.name,
         size  : obj.size,
         screen: obj.screen
      }, val);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
```

this method convert json string to object, you can access first item in `components` just like :

```
obj.components[0].category
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use it.

```
$.param(YourjsonObj);
```

this will convert json object to string.

Comment: OP asked for "parsing" - converting to a string is the opposite of parsing.